# Xamarin MPMusicPlayerController.NowPlayingItem: dynamic registrar has been linked away

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

It seems Property NowPlayingItem for MPMusicPlayerController of Type SystemMusicPlayer is completely broken.

In my existing App as well as in a fresh project, these lines of code

```
var musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.SystemMusicPlayer;

var x = musicPlayerController.NowPlayingItem;
```

Leads to this exception:

*ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Can't lookup the Objective-C class 0x1cf6e8630 (7522073724) when the dynamic registrar has been linked away.
  at ObjCRuntime.Class.LookupClass (System.IntPtr klass, System.Boolean throw_on_error) [0x00067] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:232 
  at ObjCRuntime.Class.Lookup (System.IntPtr klass) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:203 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject[T] (System.IntPtr ptr) [0x0003b] in <75e8f2cafde249969958834208668188>:0 
  at MediaPlayer.MPMusicPlayerController.get_NowPlayingItem () [0x00003] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/MPMusicPlayerController.g.cs:456*

I tried to fix this exception by adding

> --optimize=-remove-dynamic-registrar

Now I receive another exception:

*ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException
  Message=The ObjectiveC class '_MPMusicPlayerMediaItemProxy' could not be registered, it does not seem to derive from any known ObjectiveC class (including NSObject).
  Source=Xamarin.iOS
  StackTrace:
  at Registrar.DynamicRegistrar.Lookup (System.IntPtr class, System.Boolean throw_on_error) [0x00075] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/DynamicRegistrar.cs:942 
  at ObjCRuntime.Class.LookupClass (System.IntPtr klass, System.Boolean throw_on_error) [0x00021] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:227 
  at ObjCRuntime.Class.Lookup (System.IntPtr klass) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:203 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject[T] (System.IntPtr ptr) [0x0003b] in <75e8f2cafde249969958834208668188>:0 
  at MediaPlayer.MPMusicPlayerController.get_NowPlayingItem () [0x00003] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/MPMusicPlayerController.g.cs:456*

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi , I have checked the line code in my local site , there is no problem . I think you can add a logic before use `NowPlayingItem` , if not be `null` then call it .

Answer (score 0):

After checking in my local site , there is no problem running project .

In addition ,better adding judegment before using playing item , in case of no item be plying at that time .

```
var musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.SystemMusicPlayer;

var x = musicPlayerController.NowPlayingItem;

if(null != x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---playing item is ---" + x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you on the most current version of Xamarin and XCode? I updated everything 2 days ago.

Comment: @AdrianWaeber No , Xcode is `11.4.1` , Xamarin.iOS is `13.16.0.13` .